# Mapping value from alias column into @Entity Class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, dao

Is there any possible way to map value from alias column in query for my @Entity Class? For example, for this case there are new columns : first name and last name which is not exist in Transaction Table. Is there any way to map the value into Transaction @Entity Class?

Example entity and dao

@Entity

```
import java.sql.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Transaction")
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @Column(name="customer_id")
    private String customerId;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
```

@TransactionDAO

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TransactionDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Transaction, Long>,  QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Transaction>{
    @Query(value = "SELECT customer_id, SUBSTR (customer_name, 1, 10) as first_name, SUBSTR (customer_name, 11, 20) as last_name FROM Transaction WHERE customer_id=:#{#customerId}", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Transaction> selectByTransaction(@Param("customerId") String customerId);

}
```

If i use @Column annotation for first_name and last_name, there will be an error because two of that column is not existing in Transaction Table

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to map output of a Query to different model. Answer here is Projection via Interface. You can create interface with field names you want to receive from Query or Repository method. For exaple if you want to receive only firstName and lastName you create Interface like this one below. Other fields will be omitted. Fields in Interface can be diffrent than fields in your @Entity class.

```
interface TransactionProjection {
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();
}
```

Helpful links:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections